# How to pass state to child component with function based React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I try to pass uploaded file to the child component that both parent and child components are the function based.

I am using React, TypeScript and Material-UI

Parents

```js
import React from 'react';
import Child from './Child';

const Parent:React.FC =() => {
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState(null);
  const onChangeFile = (e:any) => {
    setFile(e!.target.files[0]);
  }
  return(
    <div>
    <input
      accept="*.*"
      onChange={onChangeFile}
      id="uploadFile"
      type="file" />
    <Button
      onClick={() => document.getElementById('uploadFile')!.click()}
      component='span'>
      Upload file
    </Button>
    <Child files={file: File}>
    </div>
```

Child

```js
import React from 'react';
const Child:React.FC = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      {{ props }}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Child
```

At this point, I just want to print out the file's information that I have `{{ props }}`. I am a newbie to React and please tell me anything I did wrong. Thanks in advance!
**EDIT**
I changed Child,

```js
const Child:React.FC = ({files}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      { files }
    </div>
  )
}
```

then it throws error,

```
property 'files' does not exist on type '{children?:ReactNode; }'
```

**EDIT2**
Following to @EarlePoole, I changed my code.
Parents

```js
const Parent:React.FC = () => {
 //...
 <Child file={file} />
```

Child

```js
const Child:React.FC =(props) => {
  return(
  <div>
    {props.file.file}
  </div>
  )
}
```

In parent component, I got this error

```
Type '{ file: any; } is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & {children ?:ReactNode; }'. Property 'file' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode}'
```

In Child component,

```
Property 'file' does not exist on type '{children?:ReactNode; }'
```

Comment: what value does props output?

Comment: Should be`props.files`. Assuming that file is a string not an actual file representation

Comment: { props.files }

Comment: probably when hes defining the component he could do: `const Child:React.FC = ({files}) => {....`

Comment: @RohanBhangui name of files.

Comment: @Dupocas why is it `{props.files}` ? isn't it `{props.file`} ??

Comment: Because you are naming it `files` : `<Child files={file: File}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you did provide the typings for your functional component, you did not specify the `generic` type for `React.FC`.

You should define an interface for the props of your functional component, and supply it as the generic type.

```
interface ChildProps {
  files: any; // try not to use any.  
}

const Child:React.FC<ChildProps> = ({files}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      { files }
    </div>
  )
}
```

On my example, I used `any`, as I am unsure the exact type of `files`. You should avoid using `any`, and replace it with the respective type.

Answer (score 1):

In your child, if you put `{{props}}` in your div to be printed out, it's going to likely give you [object Object] or something, because that is what props is.

In your parent you have this code `<Child files={file: File}>`. This assigns your `{file: File}` object to `props.files` in your Child component, which can then be accessed, from within your Child component, by doing `props.files.file` which will return the `File` item.

To avoid confusion and redundancy I would recommend you change your Child props assignment in your Parent component to `<Child file={file}>`.

Comment: I edited, but it still throws error. I edited my post.

Comment: Try changing your Child's component argument back to `props`, i.e. `const Child:React.FC<ChildProps> = props => {......`, and then run `console.log('props:', props)` inside of your Child component, but before the return, and come back with what your console gives you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use interface in typescript to do this.
suppose you have a state and setState in parent component to pass it on child component.

```
    interface ChildProps { 
        state: String; 
        setState: (str: String) => void;
    }
    const Chlid : React.FC<ChildProps> = ({state, setState}) => {
     // we can how directly use state and setState in child.
    }
```